# Replace a string in Yaml file using python

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

I am trying to replace a string in my yaml file using python, the yaml files looks as below

file: a.yml

```
- hosts: computer1
  history: delete 

  tasks:
    - include: files/docker.yml
    - include: files/ansible.yml
    - include: files/wonder.yml
```

so I want to replace "files/docker.yml" to "bin/docker.yml", similar for the rest of them. I tried

```
fin = open("a.yml", "rt")
fopen = open("a.yml", "wt")
for line in fin:
    fopen.write(line.replace('files/', 'bin'))
fin.close()
fopen.close()
```

But this peace of code is turning it into a blank file. any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to re-read how file pointers are handled. Then read the string in all at once and write the replaced string back to the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
with open("a.yml", "rt") as fp:
    content = fp.read()
    content = content.replace("files/", "bin/")

with open ("a.yml", "wt") as fp:
    fp.write(content)
```